# Deleting multiple records in laravel using foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to delete multiple images using product_id, I am able to delete one image at a time but am figuring out how i can insert a variable like $i=0 to a loop over but it does not work in laravel.
so far this is my code

```
   public function ImageDelete($slider_id)
{
    //int $i=0; Had introduced this but doesn't work
    $slider = Products::findOrFail($slider_id);
       foreach($slider as $product){
          $product_images=$slider->images()->get();
           $image_path = public_path().'\images2\\'.$product_images[0]->filename;
           File::delete($image_path);
         //$i++;
    }
    $slider->delete();

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Pics deleted successfully!']);
}
```

Comment: Hi dear friend. try `$slider = Products::where('id',$slider_id)->get();` if you have multiple records with the same value of `id`.

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks the images are in the folder, one product can have multiple images so my problem is deleting all the images of that product in its path.

Comment: Have you tried `foreach` on `$product_images`? Because you have multiple images for one product.  use `foreach` on `$product_images ` and change `$image_path` like this:
`$image_path = public_path().'\images2\\'.$product_image->filename;`

Comment: @MohammadAliyari, If I try that I get an error Undefined variable: product_images but when i put in the foreach loop and add $product_images[0]->filename it works but delete only one image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`findOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions) method return only one item. So you cannot iterate over it.

You can use the [`each` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-each)

```php
$product = Products::findOrFail($id);
$images = $product->images()->get();

$images->each(function ($file, $key) {
  $filePath = public_path("images2/") . $file->filename;
  File::delete($filePath);
});

// Delete the product
$product->delete();
```

Comment: Thanks but how to implement this part ($value, $key)

Comment: I updated my answer. Please read the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) regarding collection and their methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
   public function ImageDelete($slider_id)
{
    $product = Products::find($slider_id);

    $product_images=$product->images()->get();

       foreach($product_images as $product_image){
           $image_path = public_path().'\images2\\'.$product_image->filename;
           File::delete($image_path);
        }
    $product->delete();

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Pics deleted successfully!']);
}
```